# How to delete container after building in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a frontend-container, which builds the react-app as static files in global volume. I don't need this container after building anymore. How to delete it after docker-compose build?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

RUN rm -rf node_modules
```

Comment: You mention docker compose but only have a Dockerfile. What else are you doing with it? I see from your `rm` that you probably want to remove build tools and just leave the build result. Normally you would use the [builder pattern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for this, and just copy out the `dist/` artifacts into some other image. Also FYI if this is useful for you: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a multi-stage build. It works like this:

1. Stage 1: install the compiler and compile
2. Stage 2: build the final image

Stages 1 and 2 take place in different containers.

You should have it like this:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:16-alpine3.12 as build

WORKDIR /build
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

RUN rm -rf node_modules


# Stage 2
FROM alpine:latest as run

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /build/* .
```

Read more in the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/